# how to retrieve an attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do i get 'id' attribute from a checkbox?

```
<ul class="tags-list">

<li><input type="checkbox" alt="addtag" class="addtag" name="checked_name[]" id="71"><span class="tag-val">1974 </span></li>
```

etc.
It's return that I need:

```
$('input.addtag').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

But returns on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LF8hB/3/).
On my page, its returns [object Object]

Comment: you could try `this.id`

Comment: Its working fine..@Pete why is this issue is real question..not just suggesting altenatives

Comment: You need to show us enough of the code that *doesn't work* for us to reproduce the problem. At the moment, my best guess is that on your page, `$` isn't jQuery.

Comment: it's working fine here, i have checked.

Comment: @Pilot I think op  said the fiddle works (just bad English)

Comment: Good idea is to use console.log() instead of alert() for debug.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in version  jQuery.
Using this.id was helped